# Converting a number to corresponding text using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Utilizing the `OEHR_EMPLOYEES` table on Oracle Apex, I would like to convert the `DEPARTMENT ID` column values to corresponding words. For example, `DEPARTMENT ID` with a value of 10 will become `'HR'`, `DEPARTMENT ID` with a value of 20 will become `'Finance'`, etc. The `DEPARTMENT ID` is currently a Number data type. I am not even sure where to begin with this task..

Comment: Don't know about Apex, but in Oracle you can use decode https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/DECODE.html#GUID-39341D91-3442-4730-BD34-D3CF5D4701CE function or inner join with separate table of departments which will translate IDs to Names

Comment: Sample data and expected data would help. Are you asking how to do a lookup in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The database should hold the values and you should perform a join to another table which has that data in it.
for example:

So you should have a first table that contain data(people for example)

```
ID name address deparmentID
1 hadi   tehran  10
2 mahsa  saqqes  20
```

And then another table which has a list of the department

```
id department
10 HR
20 Finance
```

Then you would do a join between these tables

```
select people.name, department.department
from people, department
where people.deparmentID= department.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (please include columns in future questions):

OEHR_EMPLOYEES has EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID columns
DEPARTMENTS has DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME columns

Something  like:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_name, d.department_name
FROM oehr_employees e, departments d
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id;
```

Or:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_name,
       ( SELECT  d.department_name FROM departments d WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id ) department_name
FROM oehr_employees e;
```

Comment: While this looks correct, you must be kidding suggesting the join syntax that we used in the 1980s, because explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.) were not invented then.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.  If you have both OEHR_EMPLOYEES and OEHR_DEPARTMENTS (tables), you can see that OEHR_DEPARTMENTS contains department names, mapped to department IDs.

```
--
-- ... means: more columns/rows
--

select * from oehr_employees ;
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME ... DEPARTMENT_ID ...
100         Steven      King          90
101         Neena       Kochhar       90
...                                           

select * from oehr_departments ;
DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT_NAME ...
10              Administration  ...
20              Marketing       ...
30              Purchasing      ...
40              Human Resources ...
50              Shipping        ...
60              IT              ...
70              Public Relations...
80              Sales           ...
90              Executive       ...
100             Finance         ...
```

So, you could write a JOIN like the one in the following example.  Notice that you can add more columns into the SELECT clause, in order to get the required result (eg FIRST_NAME, EMAIL, SALARY etc).

```
select 
  employee_id
, last_name
, department_name
from 
  oehr_employees join oehr_departments using ( department_id )
;

-- result
EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME   DEPARTMENT_NAME
200         Whalen      Administration
201         Hartstein   Marketing
202         Fay         Marketing
114         Raphaely    Purchasing
115         Khoo        Purchasing
...

-- another way of coding this, with table aliases 
select 
  E.employee_id
, E.last_name
, D.department_name
from 
  oehr_employees E 
  join 
  oehr_departments D on E.department_id = D.department_id 
;
-- same result as above
```

If you want to use department names that are *different* from those in the OEHR_DEPARTMENTS table, you could use a "[case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html)" to replace the numbers with strings (notice that these are *not* stored in your database, they are "generated" whenever you execute the query).

```
select 
  employee_id
, last_name
, case department_id 
    when 10 then 'HR'
    when 20 then 'Finance'
    when 30 then 'Admin'
    when 40 then 'Shipping'
    when 50 then 'Accounting'
    when 60 then 'PR'
    when 70 then 'Exec'
    when 80 then 'Estates'
    when 90 then 'Customer Services'
    when 100 then 'H&S'
    else 'other'
  end departmentname
from oehr_employees ;  -- no join required, as we use "our own" department names

-- result
EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME DEPARTMENTNAME
100         King      Customer Services
101         Kochhar   Customer Services
102         De Haan   Customer Services
103         Hunold    PR
104         Ernst     PR
105         Austin    PR
```

Instead of a case expression, you could also use [DECODE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/DECODE.html) for this purpose (as @Dornaut mentioned in a comment).